# Can I make Amchart's tooltips (AmBalloon) always visible?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, amcharts

I am using AmChart library to display a chart and I would like the tooltips to be always visible. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, I don't think there's a way to do it with balloons, but you can use the `labelText` option.

Here's an example:

```
...
"graphs": [ {
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "labelText": "[[category]]:\n[[value]]"
  } ],
...
```

The complete code is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goran90/r79xsj8L/4/).